# Can gamma matrices be real in 6 dimensions?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, spinors, dirac-matrices

I'm trying to find the really real representation of 6D gamma matrices. The problem is that "do they really exist?"

If yes, then how am I supposed to construct them? Thank you!

Comment: Euclidean or Minkowski signature?

Comment: And also (+,-,-,-,-,-) Minkowski metric or (-,+,+,+,+,+) Minkowski metric? You can only have Majorana reps in Minkowski d=2,3,4 (mod 8), but in all-plus Euclidean there  is a purely imaginary gamma rep, and in all-minus Euclidean there is a purely real rep.

Comment: How about the majorana representation in 6D? Are they purely imaginary?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Majorana representations are a minefield of inconsistent conventions and careless statements, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309890/50583 for how different prima facie contradictory claims about the existence of real representations fit  together.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly. I'd claim Majorana in 2, 3,4 mod 8, but pseudo-Majorana in 0,1,2 mod 8, with p-majorana being necessarily massless as the pseudo "charge conjugation" flips the sign of $\bar\psi \psi$ while the usual one leaves $\bar\psi \psi$ invariant. Usual Majorana gammas are real in East-coast mostly + metric and pure imaginary in the West-coast mostly minus; the conjugaton operation in both cases being an antilinear involution and so defining a "real structure" on the representation space.     Is this in agreement with your definitions?

Comment: All those confusions about reality condition is solved if you count how many real components there are in a given Gamma matrix. You can always enlarge the dimension of the matrices to work just with real matrices. Turns out that for $d=5+1$ you are going to need to double your components. You can have a 8  real component Weyl spinor for $d=5+1$.

Answer (score 5):

*(Note: This answer only addresses the question about gamma-matrices. The existence and/or properties of the associated spinor spaces and conjugations are not addressed.)*

The existence of a real representation depends on the signature. Let $(p,m)$ denote the signature in which $p$ of the gamma matrices square to $+I$ and $m$ of them square to $-I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. If $p+m=2n$ or $p+m=2n+1$, then a representation using matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ of size $2^n\times 2^n$ exists if and only if $p-m\in\{0,1,2\}$ (mod 8).

When specialized to the case $p+m=6$ that was specified by the OP, this implies that real representations using gamma-matrices of the minimal size $8\times 8$ exist only for the signatures $(4,2)$, $(3,3)$, and $(0,6)$. Real representations of this minimal size don't exist for the Minkowski signatures $(5,1)$ or $(1,5)$.

Here are explicit constructions of real representations with the signatures for which such representation are possible. First define the $2\times 2$ matrices
\begin{gather}
 X=\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1\cr 1&0\end{matrix}\right]
\hskip1cm
 Y=\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1\cr -1&0\end{matrix}\right]
\\
 Z=\left[\begin{matrix} 1&0\cr 0&-1\end{matrix}\right]
\hskip1cm
 I=\left[\begin{matrix} 1&0\cr 0&1\end{matrix}\right].
\end{gather}
For signature $(4,2)$, we have the real representation
\begin{gather}
 \gamma_1 = X\otimes X\otimes X
\hskip1cm
 \gamma_2 = X\otimes X\otimes Z
\hskip1cm
 \gamma_3 = X\otimes Z\otimes I
\\
 \gamma_4 = Z\otimes I\otimes I
\hskip1cm
 \gamma_5 = X\otimes X\otimes Y
\hskip1cm
 \gamma_6 = X\otimes Y\otimes I.
\end{gather}
This representation uses matrices of size $8\times 8$, which is the smallest possible size. To get a real representation with signature $(3,3)$, just change $Z$ to $Y$ in $\gamma_4$. To get a real representation with signature
$(0,6)$, start with the $(4,2)$ case and use
\begin{align}
 \hat\gamma_1 &:= \gamma_2\gamma_3\gamma_4 \\
 \hat\gamma_2 &:= \gamma_1\gamma_3\gamma_4 \\
 \hat\gamma_3 &:= \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_4 \\
 \hat\gamma_4 &:= \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\\
 \hat\gamma_5 &:= \gamma_5\\
 \hat\gamma_6 &:= \gamma_6.
\end{align}

Comment: What about $8\times 8$ real Weyl gamma matrices for $d=5+1$? Remember that in $d=5+1$ chirality commutes with complex conjugation so it is possible to take the $4\times 4$ Weyl gamma matrices and replace the imaginary number by a real antimsymmetric $2\times 2$ matrix with determinant equal 1.

Comment: @Nogueira  That's a good point. I was thinking of representations of the whole Clifford algebra, not just the even part; but you're right: why not consider chiral spinors, too? My own username should have reminded me of that...  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always obtain a real representation of a spinor by enlarging the dimension. I presume that this is not what you want. I presume that what you want are $8\times 8$ real gamma matrices for euclidean signature or $4\times 4$ real gamma matrices for Minkowski signature ($4\times 4$ since complex conjugation in $d=1+5$ does not flip chirality).

For euclidean signature, organizing the gamma matrices as fermionic creation-annihilation operators

$$
b_{i}^{\pm}= \Gamma_{i}\pm i\Gamma_{7-i},\,\,\,\,i=1,2,3
$$

a Dirac spinor $\psi$ will have indices $(+++,+--,---,++-)$ plus permutations of the signs, so we get 8 components, and the gamma matrices will be $8\times 8$ complex matrices. Doing a similarity transformation:

$$
\psi\rightarrow U \psi \qquad \Gamma^{m}\rightarrow U\Gamma^{m}U^{-1}
$$

We want to see if is possible to make the gamma matrices all real. It is convenient to introduce the following $B_{\pm}$ matrices:

$$
B_{\pm}\Gamma^{m}B^{-1}_{\pm}=\pm (\Gamma^{m})^{*}\qquad B_{+}=\Gamma_{1}\Gamma_2\Gamma_3\qquad B_{-}=\Gamma_{4}\Gamma_5\Gamma_6
$$

Under the similarity transformation the $B_{\pm}$ matrices should transform as

$$
B_{\pm}\rightarrow (U^{-1*}B_{\pm}U)
$$

in order to preserve the equation that defines them (they are representation dependent objects). So the similarity transformation we are seeking for is the one that implies

$$
(U^{-1*}_{\pm}B_{\pm}U_{\pm}) = 1\qquad B_{\pm}U_{\pm}=U^{*}_{\pm}
$$

If we find a $U$ that satisfies this equation for $B_{+}$ we have the similarity transformation that gives the real gamma matrices and for $B_{-}$ pure imaginary matrices.

This equation does not have solution for $B_{+}$, only for $B_{-}$. In other to see this just compute the condition for integrability of this linear equations:

$$
B_{\pm}U_{\pm}=U^{*}_{\pm} \leftrightarrow B_{\pm}B_{\pm}^{*}= 1
$$

But $B_{+}B_{+}^{*}=-1$ since $B_{+}$ is real and $B_{+}^{2}=-1$ so there is no similarity transformation $U_{+}$ that gives real gamma matrices. Nevertheless $B_{-}$ is imaginary so $B_{-}B_{-}^{*}=+1$ and the solution is easy to obtain by inspection:

$$
U_{-}=B_{+}(1+B_{-})
$$

Note that if you hit this equation by $B_{-}$ you obtain the complex conjugate of $U_{-}$:

$$
U_{-}^{*}=B_{+}(1-B_{-})
$$

If you want to obtain real gamma matrices for $SO(6)$ you may multiply each pure imaginary gamma matrix by $i$. This will change the Clifford algebra by an overall minus sign:

$$
\{\Gamma^{m}\Gamma^{n}\}=2\eta^{mn}\rightarrow \{\Gamma^{m}\Gamma^{n}\}=-2\eta^{mn}
$$

But this will not change the Lorentz transformation and can be absorbed by changing some conventions as the sign that comes in front of the Lorentz generator:

$$
\exp\left(\frac{i}{4}[\Gamma_{m},\Gamma_{n}]\theta^{mn}\right)
$$

For Minkwoski signature the organization of gamma matrices as fermionic creation-annihilation operators $b_{i}$ should be modified in order to preserve the usual creation-annihilation algebra:

$$
\{b_{i}^{\pm},b_{j}^{\pm}\}=0\qquad\{b_{i}^{+},b_{j}^{-}\}=\delta_{ij}
$$

Let us say that now the $6$-th direction is the new $0$-th time direction. You can simply do $\Gamma_{6}\rightarrow i\Gamma_{0}$ to fix the algebra. This modify the $b_3^{\pm}$ which implies that now both $\Gamma_{0}$ and $\Gamma_{3}$ are real. This will imply that

$$
B_{+}=\Gamma_{4}\Gamma_{5}\qquad B_{-}=\Gamma_{0}\Gamma_{1}\Gamma_{2}\Gamma_{3}
$$

Now the integrability condition $B_{\pm}B_{\pm}^{*}=1$ will not be satisfied for both. We get

$$
B_{\pm}(B_{\pm})^{*}=-1
$$

Note that $\Gamma_{0}\Gamma_0=-1$ since it is equal to $(i\Gamma_{6})^2=-1$. This imply that it is impossible to do a similarity transformation that gives real or imaginary gamma matrices in d=5+1 Minkowski space-time starting from $8\times 8$ Dirac gamma matrices.

However, if you diagonalize the chirality matrix $\Gamma=\Gamma_{012345}$ and look into a eigenspace you obtain $4\times 4$ gamma matrices that describes Weyl spinors. Then, if you replace $i\rightarrow J$ where

$$
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

then you obtain $8\times 8 $ real chiral gamma matrices.