# Are the fermions in 4D Euclidean $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM Majorana? If not, what are they?

Tags: spacetime, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, yang-mills, majorana-fermions

It is stated in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003055) (as well as in many other) that the fermions of $4$D *Euclidean* $\mathcal{N}=4$ Super Yang-Mills (SYM) are Majorana fermions (see eq. (42) and (43)). However it is stated in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3556) (as well as in many other) that it is impossible to have Majorana fermions in $4$D *Euclidean* space (apparently it is okay in Minkowski space).

What is the resolution of this apparent contradiction?

Comment: Equation (43) is 16-component Majorana-Weyl spinor defined in 10-dimensions to which dimensional reduction is then applied.

Comment: @bolbteppa I see. So what kind of object is it in $4$d?

Comment: It looks like there's two things going on here. One is knowing how to obtain $N=4$ SYM in 4D from $N=1$ SYM in 10D via dimensional reduction, e.g. section 7.1 [here](https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/neil.lambert/SUSYGaugeTheory.pdf). The second thing is then putting this action in Euclidean form with a Wick rotation, something along the lines of what is done around equation (3.3.16) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00734). Doing these and then adding a Faddeev-Popov ghost and gauge-fixing term gives (42). This is different to asking about the existence of Majorana/Weyl spinors in certain dimensions.

Comment: @bolbteppa Right I have done the dimensional reduction, but not the Wick rotation. In any case I still find it confusing that the $\psi$ in eq. (42) is called a *Majorana* fermion if that is true only before the Wick rotation. They do state clearly that $\psi$ satisfies the reality condition given in eq. (43). Or does it hold after the Wick rotation as well because it has $16$ components? Sometimes the $\psi$ of eq. (42) is splitted into $4$ Weyl fermions $\lambda$, which then I guess are *not* Majorana?

Comment: I'm not sure, page 107 of [this](https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/concern/theses/3484zj571) says "In [119] they point out that this Wick rotation is not technically consistent because the R-symmetry group should also be Wick rotated from SU(4)(=SO(6)) to SO(5,1)..." if you want to go deeper this might help.

Answer (score 7):

The statement about not having Majorana fermions in 4d euclidean space is misleading. In the usual Minkowski space Majorana representation the gamma matrices are all purely imaginary (purely real in the less-used (-,+,+,+) metric).  The  Minkowski space operator-valued charge conjugate fermion field   is defined by
$$\psi^c=  {\mathcal C}^{-1}\bar\psi^T\\
(\bar\psi)^c=-\psi^T {\mathcal C}
$$where
${\mathcal C}$ is a  matrix such that
$$
{\mathcal C} \gamma^\mu{\mathcal C}^{-1}= -(\gamma^\mu)^T.
$$

The field $\psi$ represents a Majorana particle when $\psi=\psi^c$. Consistency of this property requires that $(\psi^c)^c=\psi$ and this in turn requires that ${\mathcal C}$ be skew symmetric -- something that happens only in $d=2,3,4$ dimensions (mod 8).

In  the   Euclidean path integral for a Dirac field $\bar\psi$ and $\psi$ are independent Grassman variables. To get a Euclidean *Majorana* field we  simply  *define*  $\bar\psi = -{\mathcal C}\psi^T$   so that $\psi$ and $\bar \psi$ are no longer independent.

We can take the action for a Euclidean Majorana fermion to be
$$
S= \int d^4x \left\{- \frac 12 \psi^T  {\mathcal C}(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+m)\psi  \right\}.
$$
In order for this expression not to vanish due to the anticommutation property of the Grassman $\psi$  we need the operator
$$
D= {\mathcal C}(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+m)
$$
to be skew symmetric in function space (where $\partial_\mu^T=-\partial_\mu)$). This only occurs in $d=2,3,4$ (mod 8). Thus Euclidean Grassman-valued Majorana fermions only exist in *exactly the same dimensions* as their Minkowski operator-valued bretheren.  After performing the Berezin/Grassman integral we get ${\rm Det} (\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+m)$ for a Dirac field and ${\rm Pf}[{\mathcal C}(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+m)]\propto \sqrt{ {\rm Det} (\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+m)}$ for the Majorana field.

The same is true for *psudo-Majorana* fermions which are defined using the ${\mathcal T}$ matrix that obeys
$$
{\mathcal T}\gamma^\mu {\mathcal T}^{-1}= +(\gamma^\mu)^T
$$
The resulting Euclidean action
$$ 
S= \int d^4x \left\{+ \frac 12 \psi^T  {\mathcal T}(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu)\psi  \right\}
$$
is non-vanishing only when ${\mathcal T}$ is *symmetric* and this requires $d=8,9,10$ (mod 8) which is again the condition for the existence of Minkowski operator-valued pseudo-Majorana fermions. (Note that pseudo-Majorana's are necessarily massless)

The apparent contradiction in  your cited paper  is because many authors identify "Majorana" with some sort of reality condition on the gamma matrices and so worry about the  reality properties of the Clifford algebras ${\rm Cl}(p,q)$ which describe the properties of gamma matrices  when the metric has $p$ plus signs and $q$ negative ones. These reality conditions depend intricately on $p-q$ (mod 8). This is nice mathematics, but the *physical* Majorana condition requires that the analytic continuation    of the  Euclidean path-integral correlators   to the Minkowski region of momentum space coincide with the Minkowski-computed correlators, and this is related to the symmetry properties of ${\mathcal C}$ and ${\mathcal T}$ which  are indifferent to the $\pm$ signs  in the metric.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I have seen this *physical* Majorana condition before, but does it apply here? The authors give the usual reality condition in eq.(43) for their Majorana fermions in $4$d, and not the physical condition. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I don't know! I had not seen your cited  paper by Wetterich, before (I should have). My own understanding  come from the lecture notes by Hitoshi Murayama http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf. I know too little about SUSY to comment on the first paper. Indeed I failed to get to grips with SUSY when it first became popular because I was spending my days doing Euclidean-space lattice gauge theory and could not see how to translate all the SUSY  Majorana stuff to Euclidean signature.  I wish there ahd been Murayama lecture notes back in the 70's!

Comment: Indeed you can have real euclidean gamma matrices in d=10 Euclidean, because ${\mathcal T}$ is symmetric and one can Takagi-diagonalize ${\mathcal T}\to {\mathcal T}'=U^T{\mathcal T}U= {\mathbb I}$.  I did not see what the authors mean by $\psi^*$ though. Perhaps $\bar \psi$? There is no $\bar\psi = \psi^\dagger \gamma_0$ in Euclidean space.

Comment: Is it not just the complex conjugate? I.e. the eom is $- i \gamma_\mu \partial^\mu \psi + m \psi_c = 0$ with $\psi_c \equiv i \psi^*$. That's how I learned to define Majorana fermions. Of course in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM we have $m=0$.

Comment: It can't be complex conjugation as there is no notion of complex conjgation for Grassman variables in a Euclidean path integral.

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00518 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309890/2451