# Majorana fermions in Euclidean and Minkowski signatures - contradiction with Wikipedia Table

Tags: mathematical-physics, representation-theory, spinors, majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

In this wonderful lecture note on Clifford Algebra and
Spin(N) Representations, http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf

Somehow I find some inconsistency with his Tables of Euclidean and Minkowski fermions, compared with the Table of Wikipedia. (see the bottom https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor#Summary_in_low_dimensions)

Wikipedia page shows that for Euclidean fermions, even 6d (6,0) and 7d (7,0) have Majorana fermions. But his Table says NO Majorana in both 6d (6,0) and 7d (7,0).

[image]

Wikipedia page shows that for Minkowski fermions, even 8d (7,1) and 1d (0,1) or 9d (8,1)  have Majorana fermions. But his Table says NO Majorana in both 8k and 8k+1 d.

[image]

Could any expert clarify why there is a discrepancy above? In summary, in Wikipedia, out of mod 8 dimensions, Wikipedia shows that 5 out of 8 cases have Majorana fermions, in both Euclidean and Minkowski signatures. [This lecture note on Clifford Algebra and
Spin(N) Representations](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf) only said that 3 out of 8 cases have Majorana fermions, in both Euclidean and Minkowski signatures.

Here I marked the red colors for the inconsistency data of [this lecture note](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf) compared with Wikipedia Table.

See Wikipedia page :
[image]

Comment: This post is essentially a duplicate of [Is there an elegant proof of the existence of Majorana spinors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309890/2451) and [Are the fermions in 4D Euclidean $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM Majorana? If not, what are they?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/575899/2451) It is caused by different physical and mathmatical definitions/notions of Majorana spinors, cf. e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00518 .

Comment: thanks so much for the link. I wonder whether curiousmind also agrees that it can be partially resolved from his post answer? It seems the dimensions still do not match from the answer there ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an elegant proof of the existence of Majorana spinors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309890/)